# How to swich to a frame and access element in it?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I wanted to access the element with text as **Deprecated** within "http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/deprecated.html" link in selenium in chrome browser

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(driver.findElement(By.name("classFrame"))));
driver.switchTo().frame("classFrame");
```

I have used the above code but I am getting error. How do I do it?

Comment: Please, clarify the error that you're getting to help others to answer your question.

Comment: You don't need switch twice.Just remove the last line `driver.switchTo().frame("classFrame");`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  What is the specific error?  Edit your question directly to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close. Invoking `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()` not only waits but also switches [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s focus within the `<iframe>`. So to `click()` on the element with text as **Deprecated** as the the desired elements are within a `<frame>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - `cssSelector`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame[name='classFrame']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.topNav a[href^='deprecated-list']"))).click()
    ```
  - `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[@name='classFrame']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='topNav']//a[starts-with(@href, 'deprecated-list')]"))).click();
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Thanks. I tried with the above solution but still I get the same error

Comment: at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:947)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$17.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:503)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$17.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:499) at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
 at seleniumFirstCode.switchFrame.main(switchFrame.java:23)